# is it possible to open a webpage with in flash web app?

Tags: javascript, flash

hello i have a flash application that runs on web browsers as well as on desktop with some extra functionality, i use webkit for air with desktop app and i need some alternate of it for web app,

actually i want to render html in flash player and then do some processing on it and allow some operations on it,

Question is how can i open a web page in flash application in browser such that i can do the required operations on it,

any suggestion is welcome.

regards

Comment: Are you trying navigateToURL property?

Comment: no i just need to open web pages in my flash app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you can use Flex also since Flex is actually build on Flash. 
You can use one of these components :

1. http://www.deitte.com/archives/2006/08/finally_updated.htm
2. https://github.com/flex-users/flex-iframe
3. http://matthicks.com/2009/02/flex-webbrowser-component.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Flex](http://www.adobe.com/products/flex.html) then you can directly use the `HTML` component. Set its `location` property to make it go to a web-page